# Node MySQL: Return a value from a column

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using `mysql` in a Node application, Discord bot. I want to select a value from a column but am having trouble in doing so. This is my code:

```
let prefix;

connection.query(`SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`, function(error, commands) {
    if (error) throw error;

    if (commands.length) {  // the guild is in my database
        commands.forEach(value => 
            prefix = value.prefix;
            console.log(value.prefix) // doesn't fire
        }
    }
});

message.channel.send(prefix.length) // crashes [Cannot read property length of undefined]
```

I now set `prefix` in line 1 to `"3"`and it works as expected ( I think ), printing out the value in my database, which looks as follows:

```
| guildname | guildid | ownername | ownerid | prefix |
------------------------------------------------------
| MyServer  | 7373732 | Rusty     | 636363  | !      |
```

Answer (score 0):

The console log event not firing would imply empty result set from the query. 
Although it looks like this isn't the exact code you are using, the parameter list to forEach looks wrong.

```
    (value => 
        prefix = value.prefix;
        console.log(value.prefix) // doesn't fire
    }
```

Try letting the sql engine include the variable value via sql parameters instead of using string interpolation. I mean something like:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE guildid = ?',[message.guild.id], function(error, commands) { ...
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

What is the value of message.guild.id?