# SQL Select a value from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, mysql-workbench

For a Discord bot I have a command that changes the prefix of that guild, it 'works fine' as in it updates it in my database (MySQL Workbench), but the commands still triggers for ANY prefix, so if you stick any character in-front of the command it triggers instead of the one in the database.

This is my code to check the prefix:

```
let prefix = "!"; 

connection.query(`SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id}`, (error, commands) => {
  if (error) throw error;

  if (commands.length) {  //guild exists in database
    commands.forEach(value => 
        prefix = value.prefix;
        console.log(value.prefix); // returns correct prefix from database
    });
  } else {
    prefix = "!";
  }
});
```

Comment: Dont get the OP. Post some visuals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node MySQL: Return a value from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329942/node-mysql-return-a-value-from-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little challenging trying to read your code with the arrow short hands. I'm rather sure this is where your error is coming form.

```
prefix = value.prefix; console.log(value.prefix);
```

Do you mean to be logging the original value.prefix before reassigning it?

Try this code.

`commands.forEach(function(value){
    console.log(value.prefix);
    prefix = value.prefix;
})`

[Javascript Docs on .forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)